# How to revert merge?

Tags: git

I had forked a repo and made some changes then pushed it into my master branch. Then I fetched the changes from the repo I forked and merged it into my master. I got a lot of merge conflicts. I fixed them all but somewhere in the code I missed an imp change. I have not pushed that change nor have I commited it. How can I revert the merge? The commits from the repo that I had forked had old commits and my repo have my new commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you merged something into `master`, but there is some sort of problem and you want to cancel the merge and possibly start over.  In this case, I think you can get away with the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Because you haven't committed anything yet, the only real effect the merge is having is that your working directly files, and possibly your stage, are "dirty" from the merge.  The above command will reset the working and staged files to the state they were in at the HEAD commit, before you attempted the merge.  But the actual history of your branch hasn't changed yet, so you are safe in that regard.

If you are curious how you would handle this situation if you *had* committed the merge, possibly with other work now on top of that merge commit, you could use `git rebase` to a direct commit.  Considerthe following diagram:

```
... A --- B --- C --- F ...  master
     \               /
      --- D --- E ---        feature
```

Here, `feature` diverged from `master` at commit `A`, but then was merged back into `master` at merge commit `F`.  Now you want to remove that merge commit.  You can rebase `master` to commit `A` as follows:

```
git rebase <SHA-1 of commit A>
```

Git will replay all the commits from `master` on top of `A`, however it will *ignore* the merge commit which happened at `F`.  The default behavior is to ignore merge commits and follow the main parent's path backward, so this is one way to handle this situation.

Comment: You are a rockstar Tim. Thanks for the detail explanation. I am learning a lot